# RabbitMQ not loading with latest version of Erlang

Tags: amazon-ec2, erlang, rabbitmq

I've installed Erlang from source:

otp_src_R16B01.tar.gz

When I run `erl` at prompt:

```
[ec2-user@ip-100-XX-40-55 ~]$ erl
Erlang R16B01 (erts-5.10.2) [source] [64-bit] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.10.2  (abort with ^G)
1>
```

When I run `sudo rabbitmqctl status` the version is R14, not R16:

```
`status of node 'rabbit@ip-100-XX-40-55' ...
[{pid,1837},
 ...
 {erlang_version,
     "Erlang R14B04 (erts-5.8.5) [source] [64-bit] [rq:1] [async-threads:30]....
```

How can I run rabbitmq-server with erlang version R16B01?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure, that the right `erl` is in your path first. Try `which erl` and you should see, that it finds the R14B04 and that is why Rabbit starts with it. You can try trhee things:

- uninstall R14B (if you need only current version of Erlang)
- adjust `PATH` variable (if you want to keep the old version)
- use [kerl](https://github.com/yrashk/kerl) if you want to manage multiple Erlang releases

`kerl` is really great, because it is able to adjust path for you with simple script. All you need to do is type three commands:

```
kerl build R16B01 r16b01
kerl install r16b01 /path/to/install/dir/
. /path/to/install/dir/activate
```

You will have to repeat the last step every time, you start a new terminal or put that command in configuration file.

You can also download packaged version of Erlang from the [repository](http://erlangcentral.org/downloads/)